# Servlet not recognising JSON?

Tags: java, json, servlets

I'm getting the following strack trace and not sure why:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [BuddyController] in context with path [/gbserver] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2904)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1681)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at com.mathanv.gb.dao.BuddyDao.registerBuddy(BuddyDao.java:50)
    at com.mathanv.gb.controller.BuddyController.doPost(BuddyController.java:53)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

The above strack trace is being generated by the following code:

```
JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
```

And I have the following structure:
[image: Structure]

Any Ideas why I'm getting the error?

Comment: Consider (in the mid-to-long term) learning something like [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to deal with third-party libraries for your project. It's kind of scary, but IDEs basically punt on dependency management.

Comment: Thanks alot mate, pretty new to this stuff and dependency is a new problem that I have come across lately. Always trying to learn best practices! Any good places I can start reading up on basics of Maven?

Comment: The official website would be one. It's the kind of tool where it usually helps having a project that already works to poke at and investigate. Luckily, that's pretty much what Maven "archetypes" do already, and the tutorial starts you out with one. So create a simple webapp archetype, and run `mvn tomcat:run` to see if that works, then work with that as a base. Sites like mvnrepository.com help you figure out what you need to add libraries to a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include Commons Lang in your lib; apparently your JSON library depends on it. (Specifically, the exception you're seeing is because `org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableRuntimeException` — see http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException.html — is not in your classpath.)